# Appropriate stat test for multiple 3x3 tables

Tags: categorical-data, contingency-tables

In my study, each subject produces a 3x3 contingency table.So I have a table of counts of how many times a subject  responded X Y Z in condition A, B or C. All the columns sum up to 50 (num of trials in the task).

A  B C

X 20 15 25

Y 20 15 20

Z 10 20 5

I have multiple such tables. I want to know if it's correct to pool all the data together and run a chi square or there is another thing I can do (something that includes random factors)?

Comment: What hypotheses do you intend to test??

Comment: That counts will change XYZ across conditions ABC

Comment: Why not do an N by 3 by 3 analysis? Or have I misunderstood your scientific question?

Comment: You mean as an anova?

Comment: Please add some more information, maybe some example tables, and exṕlain the nature of the tasks. Maybe some kind of logistic regression could be used